# Need to measure HTTP request latency and send result to graphite depending on the contents of the Akamai headers

Tags: python, httplib

I'm not a programmer.

I have been looking at a way to write a python script to measure the latency of a web request to an Akamai URL and send this data to graphite via statsd depending on whether the Akamai cache reports a HIT or MISS so that I can see graphically over time the difference in latency of HITs and MISSes.

What I have so far:

Send a request to a URL containing custom Headers:

```
headers = {"Pragma": "akamai-x-cache-on,akamai-x-cache-remote-on", "Accept": "text/plain"}
```

Make a HTTP Request:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("api.example.com", 80)
conn.request("GET", "/example.json?app=app1,key=keytext", '', headers)
```

Then depending on the header of the response, whether Header `x-cache` is one of a few of a possible set of answers, like TCP_MEM_HIT, TCP_HIT, or the like, send this to a statsd counter so that I can send to graphite and graph latency of HITs and MISSes.

Here is where I am out of my league. I can see my response is 200 OK by:

```
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print(r1.status, r1.reason)
```

and I can see the headers I'm looking for by:

```
print r1.getheaders()
```

Parsing the contents is where I'm stumped. I'm sure I can get example code from all over the web that I can piece together, and I can learn python. Maybe someone here can let me know if I'm off in the wrong direction, or if there's a simple answer.

Update:

An example of the current header output from my script:

```
[('content-length', '27397'), ('x-cache', 'TCP_REFRESH_MISS from a23-220-148-154.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (AkamaiGHost/6.16.4.2-13281669) (S)'), ('content-language', 'en-US'), ('expires', 'Mon, 25 Aug 2014 15:50:41 GMT'), ('vary', 'Accept-Encoding'), ('connection', 'keep-alive'), ('cache-control', 'public, max-age=297'), ('date', 'Mon, 25 Aug 2014 15:45:44 GMT'), ('content-type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'), ('x-cache-remote', 'TCP_REFRESH_MISS from a23-220-148-152.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (AkamaiGHost/6.16.4.2-13281669) (S)')]
```

The 'x-cache' and 'x-cache-remote' are interesting. For now, I'm only interested in the 'x-cache' and in this instance, 'TCP_REFRESH_MISS' is the result. I need to send a hit counter to statsd so that it will count this as a 'TCP_REFRESH_MISS'. If it were 'TCP_HIT', for example, I'd need to send that to statsd instead. For each 'x-cache' response, I also need to send the latency time of the call to Akamai. Once I have this in statsd, I send the stats to graphite so that I can see the latency of each type of HIT and MISS on a graph. This will allow our dev team to gauge whether any changes we make are affecting latency.

Comment: Can you post the header contents, with more detail of the logic you're after?

Comment: OP updated with this information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import statsd
HEADERS_OF_INTEREST = ("TCP_REFRESH_MISS", "TCP_HIT")
statsd_client = statsd.StatsClient('YOUR_STATSD_SERVER', 8125)

def process_x_cache_header(value):
    for header in HEADERS_OF_INTEREST:
        if value.startswith(header):
            statsd_client.incr("akami.{}".format(header))

for header, value in r1.getheaders():
    if header == "x-cache":
        process_x_cache_header(value)
```

For actually sending data to statsd, either of these two packages are probably what you want:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-statsd
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsd

Comment: The if statement assumes that the possible header values are known and a different action taken upon each of them. In our case, the same action will be taken no matter what the value.startswith contains, we simply want to send this value and the latency of the call to statsd.

I will look at the links you provided to determine how to best send stats to statsd. This has been helpful.

Comment: Quick update to show how easy it is to use the statds package.

Comment: This looks like good progress.
Now all I need is the timing piece, and I'll be trying this out in the dev environment.